# Haskell powerset sublists with fixed length

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

It's well known that the powerset of a list: 
`{1,2,3,4} is {{},{1},{2},{1,2},{3},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3},{4},{1,4},{2,4},{1,2,4},{3,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}}`

the haskell code I got for that problem is:

`potencia [] = [[]]`

potencia (a:bs) = potencia bs ++ map (a:) (potencia bs)

Now, how would I get a list of sublists of the same length?, for example, the list above would generate the next list of sublists of length 3 = `{{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4}}`

I'm a student sorry for my english, thanks in advance... XD

Comment: Inefficient but simple, `filter ((==n) . length) . potencia`

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot since I'm just learning XD, from your code I found a simple solution, I just added the next line of code before the one I posted: power_fixed list n = filter(\x -> length x == n)(potencia list), and it can be executed like this: power_fixed [1,2,3,4] 3

Comment: I've posted an answer with a much more efficient approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
sublists  _     0 = [[]]
sublists  []    _ = []
sublists (x:xs) n = sublists xs n ++ map (x:) (sublists xs $ n - 1)
```

Which is very similar to the code you had but just has two decreasing parameters, the length and the list.

Also, for more advanced Haskellers

```
powerset = flip runCont id . foldM step [[]]
  where step xs x = cont $ \c -> c xs ++ c (map (x:) xs)
```

is a powerset implementation without recursion using continuations. Doing the same with the `sublists` function is an interesting challenge.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm executing your code and it works fine, I'll try to understand it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking just

```
subsequencesOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
subsequencesOf n = filter ((== n) . length) . subsequences
```

Which will give you

```
> subsequencesOf 3 [1, 2, 3, 4]
[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
```

Although I find it weird that this isn't an operation in `Data.Set`, and that `Set` isn't a monad (and therefore has its own version of `replicateM`.) I guess there might be obstacles in the way there.